# The address bar of my browser won't behave since I configured it to pass by Squid

Tags: networking, firefox, proxy, squid

I have installed Squid on a computer (a Raspberry Pi) to act as a web cache proxy and have configured my system to go through it before reaching my router. Everything works fine except for this small issue.

Without going through the proxy, Firefox has this amazing feature: if I type a non-URL word in the address bar, it will use it as a search query to my default search engine.

When activating the proxy, this feature doesn't work anymore. When I enter a non-URL word I get an error page (signed by Squid proxy) that says "The requested URL could not be retrieved" and complains that it's unable to determine the correct IP.

I know I can use the search bar right next to the address bar, but old habits die hard. So I want to fix this.

**Is there a way to configure Squid to redirect any non-URL request it gets into a search query?**

Comment: Sounds like this is a known bug in Firefox. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=536955

Comment: The problem is Squid return a 403 Forbidden, where it should return a 504 Gateway Timeout. Maybe you can configure Squid to return 504?

Comment: I found this solution that works for me : http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r17250365-How-to-make-Squid-use-google-search